# JAVASCRIPT reading value from excel sheet displas a diffrent value

Tags: javascript, json, xlsx

currently, I am working on a function that is needed to import all the excel data into json objects on a website, therefore I have used the `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` utility on JS which brings me all the data to JSON on the web page. but few data are invalid which are not the same as on the excel sheet specifically date formats.

on the read method what I was following is below

```
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: "binary", 
  });
```

do I need to add anything else to get the date data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few options you have to mention in order to get the data correctly on date format

```
let readData = XLSX.read(data, {
  type: "binary",
  cellDates: true,
  dateNF: "mm/dd/yyyy;@",
});
```

Comment: thank you this works